# How to change value of variable is 3 other variables have a certain value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

I have an if statement which changes the value of the variable `currentYear` and adds 1 to it if it is the 31st of December and the timezone is more than 1. I need this because it has variables that are inputted into a cookie's expire time.

It should add 1 to the `currentYear` variable, change the `currentDate` to "1" and change the `currentMonth` to "0".

The current error with this is the `|| (0.1 < currentTimezone))` part of the statement doesn't seem to be changing anything, because even when the `currentTimezone` is less than 0.1, the statement still works.

Is this the correct way to have 3 conditions in and else if statement?

Thanks

```
const D = new Date();
let currentDate = D.getDate();
let currentMonth = D.getMonth();
let currentYear = D.getFullYear();
let currentTimezone = D.getTimezoneOffset()/60;

/* Change year if end of year */
if ((currentMonth == "11" && currentDate == "31") || (0.1 < currentTimezone)) {
    currentYear = currentYear + 1;
    currentDate = "1";
    currentMonth = "0";
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: || means OR && means AND. If all statements must be true in your if use &&